# Declaring multiple structs and overlaying them on already allocated memory

Tags: c, memory, struct

I am very new to C/C++, so I know that this question is probably trivial but I don't understand how to proceed. I have allocated blocks of memory that are 512 bytes each like so (Sector is a struct of size 512 bytes): 
`char* block = (char *) malloc (sizeof(Sector));`

I have another struct that is 128 bytes in size:

```
typedef struct inode {
int fileSize;
int fileType;
int* blockPointer[30];
} inodeFile;
```

What I want to do is overlay this struct on the block. I need each block to contain 4 inode structs, but each struct may not have any values associated with it until later on in the program. So for example:

`((*inodeFile) block)->fileSize = 10;`

If I am understanding correctly, this is setting the first 4 bytes of the pointer block to fileSize. I would continue to do this for each field of the struct.

My question is, how can I do this for 4 different inodes? And since there are 4 different inodes, how can I return the values of each field for the different structs? It seems like simply saying block->fileSize wouldn't work because there can be up to four different file sizes.

Comment: Why not `(((*inodeFile) block)+1)->fileSize = 10;` (other than inevitably running up against strict aliasing problems with this scheme)

Comment: Have you considered the merits of `typedef union InodeSector { Sector sector; inodeFile inodes[4]; } InodeSector;` (with your preferred consistent capitalization/camel-case/underscored naming scheme)?  To my eyes, `Sector` and `inodeFile` are inconsistent, but consistency is beneficial.  With the `union`, you can access the data as either a Sector or as an array with 4 `inodeFile` entries.  You might still need to be aware of strict aliasing.

Comment: Try `((inodeFile*)block)[0].fileSize = 10;` (asterisk on the other side of the type name, and using `[]` to dereference so you can easily access the 2nd, 3rd and 4th by changing the index to 1, 2, or 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `union` to overlay the blocks on the sectors. Because the fields are of `int` type or pointer or size 512 there shouldn't be an alignment problem so long as the natural size is 32-bit.

```
typedef struct {
    int fileSize;
    int fileType;
    int* blockPointer[30];
} inode;

typedef union {
    unsigned char bytes[512];
    inode block[4];
} sector;

int main()
{
    sector thisec;
    thisec.bytes[511] = 0;
    thisec.block[0].fileSize = 10;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thisec.bytes[511] = 0; is superfluous. Perhaps, you wanted to say, memset(&thissect, 0, sizeof thissect); ?

Comment: It's an example, I was going to put `fread()` but I don't know where OP is getting the block data from.

Comment: Anyway, it's not `thissect` it is `thisec`. I wrote to index 511 to show the compilation works, but I am not attempting to interfere with the `fileSize` field.